# Как на next js с помощью встроенного api сохранять фотографии в папку, при получении post запроса с фотографией не могу получить req.body

Tags: next.js

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // Получаем данные из запроса
    
   console.log(req.body)
  }
```

console.log выдает такое

```
?♫??g[g????c+‼???y??)M?w?♦!T☻<?>? ??n?♣?F♂?[PF?E☼       ?B??rrMj????vf????gptf=I>?M^?♣?vv?→????[?↔?↕m?2??R♣ ‼?y☻?????'d?Y?M§<?um?#p¶♀???rkXmq>?Lx<7??%C-??∟?♫[?▲??Z?b??m?9?Y▲???oudO?[&V8??=[♥??^uI?UG??ПW??
k[?u??-??%??`H???↑?T'↑P?♀?ki;?#?*???<1??#?qp??N>C?
1???@G?k)??O?xu)?.?Fq,?U??  dg??&???I\??lm?4??WN$B????♫3???_j?-???b????48|??♫?∟??????ZA9??<r????j?9?"
??H?$☺?
??♂q ♀?♫?♦???????????GW7◄B♀P??#P♫v??↓?J??)jX?l[R?o▬??%?◄?eO???Np♠ ?Ms\M{?Kk??????_????I??d~G??i%t?g§m???M?▼☼Z?$?g??&?7u?=s???Qrlso?^\j→?f,-R@>?? ????b?3??D??↑???∟%
1       ?q??c?T5wfk{F?E?)♀>¶?????C??pP???@?z?↕F??▬?]u??▼SB?R?X?u??
?A8p???[9? ?,z?T??}t45}M?$???<?<h$T?↓?a?d????5r?g?'??}Z?F???E??U        ???∟z↕1U⌂u2-?E↔◄?????y???K  b☺P???ki?4cM?v??????u[???¶♠(e???`(?z??????UT?w)?s/u?xa?U ??∟B1?Pg???)???+?▼?}6g???j[???E,↨♫??h?\?d ?XGF???gx?,?^??a?]X?↔?mP?►{??5Q}???_h2? a???I♀?▼h?? z☻6??d?♦0??O??‼k3??/4??♣?[?x???S???_FeS????UI♥#?n??.???9]v?????0"(?X????d♀%(TFr:☻?>???D↨??s?Z?a$o-?[H|?1?↕?6?♣?B}?♀?R?????d}¶5(u???%?0????Y?\??^F???f>?J???u?c?u?↑u??☻???[YJ?↑????>Fa?2↑)??<?]?L-wrZ?xsT?☼???[?5???x?!???%e>???h???x??xc_??`I?`☺U?☼?-?k???N}?i?Г?+x? &]sN☼§??@?♀T??~????b??rG{?K↨?▼?F?9?j?∟?I¶??0?
z??‼?f?0?☺♦??#??|??V<?l∟??K? ☼?7?[↓ ?↔??b►}?⌂???→?      ?9-?`?6♦?L?▼b?☺!☼S?b?Q?kC??t?-l???↨??c_1I?<?:m*O?♀♠G♠?K☻?g?kbUVkU?⌂&G
?????9↓♥=;u?M)?.i???^??O??f??.#?u???◄"??A∟`►⌂?JVJ?9?Ik??????I?U?\??????G♦??5?6?-?????^  ???-/m?A??`c♥ ?c'?oZR?d???↨?wmk?Z???

----------------------------443071937285161249708602--
```